# Idea plugin: How to make Annotator work for normal file

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I extend Annotator class and override annotate method. but it only work for '.java' file. Could it work for other file type?

I want to achieve such a function. In a '.conf' file, there are pairs of key-value like 'key_a:val_a' and some expressions like '${key_a}'. then when my mouse cursor on one of these expressions, it could check if the key has declared value or not.

But now, I can't get the PsiElement when my mouse cursor in '.conf' file.

Comment: You need to write the entire custom language plugin: lexer, parser and so on. You can't have an Annotator for a file that IntelliJ IDEA does not know how to parse.

Comment: I am developing base on [simple_language_plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-docs/tree/master/code_samples/simple_language_plugin) . it knows how to parse already. @yole

Comment: Then please show the code of your annotator and how you're registering it in plugin.xml.